# How to write a program that adds the numbers of the longest increasing or decreasing sequence in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, sequence

I have a program that I need to write, but I have no idea how to do any of it... I've looked on other parts of the web, but most of them use 'function' and a bunch of things I haven't learned yet. I would love for someone to help me out with a basic Java solution.

The goal is:

Assume the array has at least 2 elements. Find the longest run of numbers in ary, where the longest run can either be monotonically increasing(a[i] <= a[i+1]) or monotonically decreasing. In case of a tie for the longest run, choose the longest run that occurs first. Return the sum of the elements in the longest run.

I've been trying to use a list to add all the elements.
The code I've tried so far starts off:

```
public int longestRun(int[] ary){
  int sum=0;
if(ary.length==0)
        return 0;

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

    for(int num: ary){
        if(list.size()==0 || num>list.get(list.size()-1)){
            list.add(num);
        }else{
            int i=0; 
            int j=list.size()-1;

            while(i<j){
                int mid = (i+j)/2;
                if(list.get(mid) < num){
                    i=mid+1;
                }else{
                    j=mid;
                }
            }

            list.set(j, num);
        }
        for(int b=0;b<list.size();b++){
          sum+=list.get(b);
        }
    }

    return sum;

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ["Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far** to solve the problem, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You should also take some time to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  These sorts of questions just don't work very well in the searchable-Q&A-repository format of Stack Overflow.